# Timeout issue with a dockerized phantomjs

Tags: node.js, docker, phantomjs, alpine-linux

I would like to do some test using nodejs and phantomjs inside a docker container.
All these tests work perfectly directly on a centos or debian server

> npm run test
>
> > smart-tv-portal-tests@1.0.0 test /data/SmartTVPortal/tests
> >     mocha test-*.js
>
> test suite for
>   *xxx*
>       ✓ should respond 200 OR 304 for xxx
>   (173ms)
>       ✓ should assert that the reponse is application/json
>       ✓ should be able to parse json
>       ✓ should validate JSON integrity (videos.length === 6)
>       ✓ should validate http status with phantomjs (160ms)
>       ✓ should validate carousel is loaded (761ms)
>       ✓ should check last carousel element
>       ✓ should navigate interactive in the main carousel (121ms)
>
> 8 passing (1s)

but if I run the very same test within a docker container (based either on alpine/centos/ubuntu) it fails with timeout issue

```
docker run -ti --net=host --rm --volume /data/SmartTVPortal/:/srv --workdir /srv/tests arte/hbbtv bash
```

I get

> bash-4.3# npm run test
>
> > smart-tv-portal-tests@1.0.0 test /srv/tests
> >     mocha test-*.js
>
> test suite for
>   *xxx*
>       ✓ should respond 200 OR 304 for xxx
>   (2534ms)
>       ✓ should assert that the reponse is application/json
>       ✓ should be able to parse json
>       ✓ should validate JSON integrity (videos.length === 6)
>       ✓ should validate http status with phantomjs (89ms)
>       1) should validate carousel is loaded Unhandled rejection text evaluatePage
>
> global code evaluateJavaScript@[native code]
>   evaluate@phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:390:39
>   phantomjs://code/bridge.js:121:61
>       at /srv/tests/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:989:36
>       at tryCatcher (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Function.Promise.fromNode.Promise.fromCallback (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:179:30)
>       at Horseman. (/srv/tests/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:987:29)
>       at Horseman.tryCatcher (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:10)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:12)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:574:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:554:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:533:5)
>
> Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: timeout during .waitFor() after
>   15038 ms
>       at Timeout.waitForCheck (/srv/tests/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:1643:13)
>       at Timeout.wrapper (timers.js:425:11)
>       at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
>       at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
>
> ```
> 2) should check last carousel element Unhandled rejection text evaluatePage
> ```
>
> global code evaluateJavaScript@[native code]
>   evaluate@phantomjs://platform/webpage.js:390:39
>   phantomjs://code/bridge.js:121:61
>       at /srv/tests/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:989:36
>       at tryCatcher (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Function.Promise.fromNode.Promise.fromCallback (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:179:30)
>       at Horseman. (/srv/tests/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:987:29)
>       at Horseman.tryCatcher (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseCtx (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:10)
>       at Async._drainQueue (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:143:12)
>       at Async._drainQueues (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:148:10)
>       at Immediate.Async.drainQueues (/srv/tests/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:17:14)
>       at runCallback (timers.js:574:20)
>       at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:554:5)
>       at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:533:5)
>
> ```
> 3) should navigate interactive in the main carousel
> ```
>
> 5 passing (30s)   3 failing
>
> 1) test suite for
>   *xxx*
>   should validate carousel is loaded:
>        Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
>
> 2) test suite for
>   *xxx*
>   should check last carousel element:
>        Error: Timeout of 7000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
>
> 3) test suite for
>   *xxx*
>   should navigate interactive in the main carousel:
>        Error: Timeout of 10000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

The falling part of the test is

```
it('should validate carousel is loaded', function(done) {
        this.timeout(10000);
        horseman
            .open(WEBAPP_URL)
            .waitFor(function() {
                return document.querySelector('#loadingPanel').style.visibility === 'hidden';
            }, true)
            .waitFor(function() {
                return document.querySelectorAll('.videosCarouselItem').length === 4;
            }, true)
            .then(function(res) {
                done();
            });
    });
```

I guess the problem is coming from phantom not able to interpret jquery and so can't find the selector but the problem appears only within a docker container.

Problem is the same using casperjs

I've dug a little more)
The very part that 'timeout' within the docker container is

```
  .waitForSelector('.videosCarouselItem')
  .count('.videosCarouselItem')
```

and give me the error

```
Unhandled rejection TimeoutError: timeout during .waitFor() after 15059 ms
    at Timeout.waitForCheck (/srv/tests/node_modules/node-horseman/lib/actions.js:1643:13)
    at Timeout.wrapper (timers.js:425:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:232:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:202:5)
```

Outside docker it's OK, I get a 4 (that's correct)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the inconvenience, issue was linked to our tested applciation, I had to change the URL by adding some queryparam.
I don't why it was working with a browser inside windows, or phantomjs directly on a VM but not inside a docker but now it's OK.

I found the error using the snapshot feature.